# Can't get udev rule to work

Tags: scripts, mouse, udev

I'm trying to run a script when my mouse connects.

```
#!/bin/sh

echo New mouse speed applied
id=17
speed=1
xinput set-prop $id "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" $speed, 0, 0, 0, $speed, 0, 0, 0, 1
firefox #Starting this so I'll see instantly if it worked
```

The udev rule:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0405", ATTRS{idVendor}=="145f", RUN+="/home/matthes/.mousespeed.sh"
```

The script works, I tested it manually.

```
$ udevadm info -a -p /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.1/0003:145F:0405.001A/input/input43/mouse4

looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3':
    KERNELS=="1-3"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    [...]
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0405"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="145f"
    [...]
    ATTRS{product}=="Trust Gaming Mouse"
    [...]
```

idProduct and idVendor are correct too, I can't figure out why it won't work. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Possibly for the same reason as here [Udev not running scripts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/547586/udev-not-running-scripts) i.e. `xinput` can't connect to a running xserver

Comment: @steeldriver nope, not working sadly. I think it should at least start firefox, right?

Comment: How should it know which xserver / display to start firefox on?

Comment: I'll take that as a no. I did it as in your link, added both exports, but that didn't help

Comment: The correct way is to use `xorg.conf`, could you add prop listing of that device from xinput.